# Problem of sending 2 recaptcha v3 token for 2 button in cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, recaptcha-v3

I have two buttons in my cshtml file. For the first button I can send recaptcha v3 token to my controller. But if I try to send token from my second buttons , It sends null as a token to the controller. My code is below and I do not know what is wrong. How can I send v3 token from the second button?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.text)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagenumber)
    <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Show comments" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.text)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagenumber)
    <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Show comments" />
}





<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=mysitekey
"></script>
<script>grecaptcha.ready(function () {
    grecaptcha.execute('mysitekey', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {

        document.getElementById("token").value = token;


        });

    });</script>
```

Comment: Your `<input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" />` should have a `token` class not a token id. Then you get the two inputs by class and replace their value. Also, change the ids of your `submit` inputs like `submit1` and `submit2` or something.

Comment: thank you for your response! what do you mean  by saying " should have a token class not a token id. Then you get the two inputs by class and replace their value." ? I did not understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getElementById` which returns the first element it finds with a matching `Id`, that's why only one form is working for you (Ids should be unique and you shouldn't have two elements with the same id).

That's why we have classes, to identify multiple elements. So just replace the `id="token"` with `class="token"` on the two inputs then you can replace their value like this:

```
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.token');
    elements.forEach(function(element){
        element.value = token;
    });
```

#### Update

The `ActionLink` is a tag helper that gets rendered on the server to an anchor tag `<a>`, and since you're acquiring your token on the clientside you have to grab that anchor tag and append your token as a parameter to its `href` attribute using Javascript.

Something like this:

```
let element = document.querySelector("Your link id or class");
let attribute = element.getAttribute('href');
element.setAttribute('href', attribute + '?token=' + token);
```

Comment: how can I use this in "Html.ActionLink"? I mean I want to send token in Html.ActionLink.

Comment: @exento You have to append it to the anchor tag `href` attribute as a parameter.